# MySQL - ResultSet.updateString() java.sql.SQLException: Column not found

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to select rows from my a certain table in mu database and update my table based on the results. After a lot of research it seems that updateString() and updateRow() is the way to go. Here's my code, please note that `state` is a global variable of the `Statement` type:

```
public void updateMyRows(Connection conn){
    try {
        int id;
        String firstName, lastName, userName, pwd;
        state = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT idP, firstName, lastName, salt FROM PERSON";
        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            id = rs.getInt("idP");
            firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            userName = UserNamePwd.userNameGen(lastName, firstName, id);
            pwd = UserNamePwd.passWordGen(lastName, firstName, id);
            rs.updateString("userName", userName);
            rs.updateString("pwd", pwd);
            rs.updateRow();
        }
        rs.close();
        state.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

doing this gives me this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'userName' not found.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.updateString(ResultSetImpl.java:7788)
        at AddUsersToDB.addUserNamesAndHash(AddUsersToDB.java:79)
        at AddUsersToDB.main(AddUsersToDB.java:96)
```

Yet 'userName' is the exact name of one of the columns I want to update... what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `userName` and `pwd` columns in your query in order for these columns to be available in the result set.  I might just go with `SELECT *` here to grab every column available, though you could just add `userName` and `pwd` to the select list.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getInt("idP");
    firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
    lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
    userName = UserNamePwd.userNameGen(lastName, firstName, id);
    pwd = UserNamePwd.passWordGen(lastName, firstName, id);
    rs.updateString("userName", userName);
    rs.updateString("pwd", pwd);
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed userName and pwd in your select sql.

It should be :

String sql = "SELECT idP, firstName, userName, pwd, lastName, salt FROM PERSON";